# Issue with adding a new node in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to add a new node in my XML file, but I get InvalidOperationException due to the current position of the navigator.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<dictionary xmlns="RecnikSema.xsd">

<sentiments>

  <sentiment word="napustiti">-2</sentiment>

</sentiments>  

</dictionary>
```

and schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="dictionary">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="sentiments">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="sentiment">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="word"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:double" name="value"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The code in C# which I am using to add a new node looks like this:

```
XmlDocument dictionary= new XmlDocument();
dictionary.Load(@"C:\Users\Luka\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TSA\TSA\Dictionary.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = dictionary.CreateNavigator();

navigator.MoveToChild("dictionary", @"C:\Users\Luka\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TSA\TSA\RecnikSema.xsd");
navigator.MoveToChild("sentiments", @"C:\Users\Luka\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TSA\TSA\RecnikSema.xsd");
navigator.MoveToChild("sentiment", @"C:\Users\Luka\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TSA\TSA\RecnikSema.xsd");

navigator.InsertAfter("<sentiment word=\"" + token + "\">" + value + "</sentiment>");
```

The exception is occuring on the last line, on `InsertAfter`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey Mario, that is just a mistake I made during the translation of the variables and attributes when posting here.

So, the exception is InvalidOperationException, and the explanation is:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Operation is not valid due to the current position of the navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make it simple mate by using XDocument.

The new version of C# has got this class that makes it easy to manipulate Xml. Thus, it also supports Xml Linq as well.

Here is the quick solution that may be useful for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\amit\SkyDrive\code\WebApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\xml.xml");
            XElement root = new XElement("sentiment");
            root.Value = "3";
            root.Add(new XAttribute("word", "napustiti"));
            XNamespace nsSys = "RecnikSema.xsd";
            document.Element(nsSys + "dictionary").Element(nsSys + "sentiments").Add(root);
            document.Save("c:\newFile.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I've tried with this code, but nothing is written to XML as I get NullRefferenceException with message Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EDIT:
Removing nsSys from document.Element removed the exception. It works now!

Comment: Good job mate...you are getting better.

Answer (score 0):

In `MoveToChild()`, the second argument is the XML namespace, not the location of your document. In your case, you have set `xmlns="RecnikSema.xsd"`. This means `MoveToChild` cannot find a match, so when you get to `insertAfter`, the current node is still the root node `<dictionary>`, and it attempts to create XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<dictionary xmlns="RecnikSema.xsd">
    <sentiment word="napustiti">-2</sentiment>
</dictionary>
<sentiment word="foo">5</sentiment>
```

This has 2 root elements and so you get the error

Instead you need to pass `"RecnikSema.xsd"` as the argument.:

```
navigator.MoveToChild("dictionary", "RecnikSema.xsd");
navigator.MoveToChild("sentiments", "RecnikSema.xsd");
navigator.MoveToChild("sentiment", "RecnikSema.xsd");
```

I'm not sure you meant to set this as the namespace as it is the Schema file, so maybe you mean this?:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<dictionary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="RecnikSema.xsd">
    <sentiments>
        <sentiment word="napustiti">-2</sentiment>
    </sentiments>
</dictionary>
```

**C#**

```
XmlDocument dictionary= new XmlDocument();
dictionary.Load(@"C:\Users\Luka\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TSA\TSA\Dictionary.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = dictionary.CreateNavigator();

navigator.MoveToChild("dictionary", "");
navigator.MoveToChild("sentiments", "");
navigator.MoveToChild("sentiment", "");

navigator.InsertAfter("<sentiment word=\"" + token + "\">" + value + "</sentiment>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you did not specify the maxOccurs (default is 1) and you allready added on element. See http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp

> maxOccurs Optional. Specifies the maximum number of times the sequence
>   element can occur in the parent element. The value can be any number>=
>   0, or if you want to set no limit on the maximum number, use the value
>   "unbounded".  Default value is 1

so your Solution for multiple sentiments:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="dictionary">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="sentiments">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="sentiment">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="word"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:double" name="value"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I would prefer using Microsoft xsd tool to generate a CLR Class -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx and using XMLSerializer -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx